# Removing entry from Ignite Cache when we have lock on the same entry

Tags: ignite, distributed-transactions, distributed-caching

Is it possible to remove entry from cache when we have lock on the same entry ? This works randomly

Ignite cache here is TRANSACTIONAL cache.

Lock lock = ignite.cache(cacheName).lock(key);

lock.lock()

/** perform some operation **/

ignite.cache(cacheName).remove(key);

/** perform some operation **/

lock.unlock()

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be related to local/remote affinity of this key, and I also think you should not do that. Use lock to guard other operations on the cache, not the operations on this key.

If you have a reproducer which demonstrates this behavior, please file an [IGNITE](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/IGNITE) ticket or write to developers list about that.